# Change default behavior for Unauthenticated users in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to change to where non-logged in user to be redirected when they try to access pages which required user to be logged in.

I have tried in `Exceptions/Handler.php` to change it like this

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('/users/login'));
}
```

But when I try to access such page I've got error

> InvalidArgumentException Route [/users/login] not defined.

My route in web.php is

```
Route::get ('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@getLoginPage', 'before' => 'guest']);
```

It's also same if I put the home `/`

> Route [/] not defined.

Is this the correct place where this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give a route name and not an url,
Inside the array do this:

```
Route::get ('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@getLoginPage', 'before' => 'guest', 'as' => 'user.login']);
```

And call it like this:

```
return redirect()->guest(route('user.login'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To call your login route using the `route()` helper you have to give a name to your route.

```
Route::get ('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@getLoginPage', 'before' => 'guest'])->name('users.login');
```

So you will be able to do

```
    return redirect()->guest(route('users.login'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.